# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable while use the model

Tags: model, pytorch, call, nonetype

I'm using PyTorch for training GCN, I have a simple model that saved using this command:

```
torch.save(MyNet().state_dict(), PATH)
```

Then I load it by doing the following:

```
model = MyNet()
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH))
model.eval()
```

But then when I tried to input the data as follows:

```
output = model(dataset)
```

I got this error for the previous line:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

I don't know what's the reason for that, could you please help me?

Comment: Could you check if `model is None` right after `model = MyNet()`?

Comment: May the problem comes from the way you save your model. You instanciate your model at same time you save it. Did you train your model before you saved it? If yes, it is that model you have to model. I find this `torch.save(MyNet().state_dict(), PATH)` weird. I think it should be something like this `torch.save(model.state_dict(), PATH)` and `model ` is the trained model.